# Fancybox Load IFrame on Page Load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, fancybox-2

I'm building a site that has small news posts (Around 300 characters) and I want to let users share these on twitter etc.  The problem is that I don't particularly want the twitter users to be redirected to a dedicated page for the post so I was wondering if it was possible to redirect them to a page on my site and allow the post to popup as the user enters?

I've seen a snippet of code for this on the fancybox website but it uses html, where as this would be a full php page loading up in iframe format. Is this possible?

Comment: if you open an external page inside an iframe (with or without fancybox), then it doesn't really matter if the opened page is php or asp or html.

Comment: Cheers @JFK but what I really want to know is if you can open the IFrame on Page Load when the page link is passed to the new page, i.e. www.website.co.uk/notes?opennote=123456 = Will open up www.website.co.uk/notes - then automatically open up www.website.co.uk/notes?note=123456 as an IFrame over the top of the parent page

Comment: I don't see the difference between `www.website.co.uk/notes?opennote=123456` and `www.website.co.uk/notes?note=123456` -or- why you cannot get only one or the other -or- why one iframe has to call another iframe!? If reformulating the question to : "Can you pass this URL `www.website.co.uk/notes?note=123456` to the browser so it opens automatically that page (note=123456) in fancybox iframe?", my answer would be: "yes, it would be possible"